# How to update Gnuplot on Meteohub server?

Tags: server, gnuplot, version, updates, weather

Good day,
I have a problem with the Gnuplot version, on my miniaturized weather server. I currently have a version 4.2 , this version is very old.

How to update to the lates version ? It is possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, gnuplot 4.2 is very old. Do you have a bit more information? What weather server? Which operating system? I would say you download it from the gnuplot homepage and copy it on your machine. What have you tried so far? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hello, This is Meteohub server, with linux kerner. The server has gnuplot 4.2 installed in it from the beginning. 
I'm a beginner and I'm just learning how everything works. I need an up-to-date system for further work.
This is page producer https://wiki.meteohub.de/Main_Page 
I tried command: apt-get install gnuplot. That replaces actual version... it didn't work

Comment: I tried dowload new version it from gnuplot homepage, and at the server command prompt i wrote: gnuplot update "file path" unfortunatel i did not find instructions. 

On my local computer enough write apt-get install. :(